# How to call batchWriteItemAsync to load DynamoDB in scala/spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to run batchwriteAsync to load data into DynamoDB by Scala(Spark), but meet error below when it is run, may I ask how to process batchwriteAsync correctly in Scala?

**Code**

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model._
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.{AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClientBuilder, AmazonDynamoDBAsync, AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder, AmazonDynamoDB}
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext,Future}

val POOL_SIZE = 3
val client: AmazonDynamoDBAsync = AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(REGION).build()
// init threads pool
val jobExecutorPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE)
// create the implicit ExecutionContext based on our thread pool
implicit val xc: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(jobExecutorPool)

var contentSeq = ...
val batchWriteItems: java.util.List[WriteRequest] = contentSeq.asJava

def batchWriteFuture(tableName: String, batchWriteItems: java.util.List[WriteRequest])(implicit xc: ExecutionContext): Future[BatchWriteItemResult] = {
    client.batchWriteItemAsync(
      (new BatchWriteItemRequest()).withRequestItems(Map(tableName -> batchWriteItems).asJava)
    )
  }

batchWriteFuture(tableName, batchWriteItems)
```

**Error:**

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.concurrent.Future[com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.BatchWriteItemResult]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.BatchWriteItemResult]
    client.batchWriteItemAsync(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.batchWriteItemAsync` is a Java API so it returns a `java.util.concurrent.Future`

Your method `batchWriteFuture` has a return type of `scala.concurrent.Future`

Try converting your DynamoDB call to scala like

```
def batchWriteFuture(tableName: String, batchWriteItems: java.util.List[WriteRequest])(implicit xc: ExecutionContext): Future[BatchWriteItemResult] = {
    client.batchWriteItemAsync(
      (new BatchWriteItemRequest()).withRequestItems(Map(tableName -> batchWriteItems).asJava)
    ).asScala // <---------- converting to scala future
  }
```